# Sidebar list style in SwiftUI does not work

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I created a list inside a view in SwiftUI, and I set its style to `.sideBar`, but it's not getting applied. There is no expand button. What could be the issue? Any solutions? (My minimum deployment is iOS 16.2)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListTestView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(content: {
                Text("...")
                Text("...")
                Text("...")
                Text("...")
            }, header: {
                Text("Hedaer")
                    .textCase(nil)
            })
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
    
}

#Preview {
    ListTestView()
}
```

[image: preview image]

Comment: Did you try landscape?

Answer (score 0):

The `.sidebar` list style is meant to just add a chevron to the header. Allowing the user to collapse/expand the section.

### iOS 17+ Solution

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle/sidebar)

> On macOS and iOS, the sidebar list style displays disclosure indicators in the section headers that allow the user to collapse and expand sections.

What doesn't seem to be documented, is that you must use a `Section` that includes `isExpanded` in its initializer.

```
struct ListTestView: View {
    @State var showingFirstSection = true
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section(
                isExpanded: $showingFirstSection,
                content: {
                    Text("...")
                }, header: {
                    Text("Header")
                }
            )
        }
        .listStyle(.sidebar)
    }
}
```

When you create your `Section` with `isExpanded`, the chevron will appear as long as the list style is `.sidebar`

### iOS 16- Solution

I tried all the other `Section` initializers and none of them provided a chevron with `.sidebar` list style. Since SwiftUI is not providing the expected functionality, I recommend using a custom `Section` implementation.
This `CollapsibleSection` uses just the base `Section` initializer, and exposes a `showingContent` bindable to mimic the behavior of the `isExpanded` sections.

```
struct CollapsibleSection<C, H>: View where C: View, H: View {
    @Binding var showingContent: Bool
    var content: C
    var header: H
    
    @inlinable
    init(showingContent: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> C, @ViewBuilder header: () -> H) {
        self._showingContent = showingContent
        self.content = content()
        self.header = header()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Section(
            content: {
                if showingContent {
                    content
                }
            },
            header: {
                HStack {
                    header
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                        .rotationEffect(showingContent ? .zero : .degrees(-90))
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                showingContent.toggle()
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Use it the same as the iOS 17+ solution

```
CollapsibleSection(
    showingContent: $showingFirstSection,
    content: {
        Text("...")
        Text("...")
        Text("...")
    },
    header: {
        Text("Header")
    }
)
```

Comment: There's a compile error "'init(isExpanded:content:header:)' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer". What if my minimum deployment version is older than iOS 17.0?

Comment: @HoyeonLee updated my answer with one that works on targets below 17. Unfortunate that SwiftUI doesn't default to what is expected